# Ubuntu pass information to a text file during process execution

Tags: ubuntu

My issue is that I have a function call it function1 which runs indefinitely. The function itself echo's "hello" every 1 second. Using the command:

`function1 >> temp.txt`

Every 1 second if I am to view the file temp.txt I should see a new line with "hello". However what's happening is that the function doesn't write to the file until its finished running. Therefore if I am to kill the function nothing will be written. Does anyone know of something I can do in this situation that will basically dynamically update temp.txt?

I have a python script set up the following way:

`while [1>0]:
   print "hello"
   time.sleep(1)`

Therefore this will always be running. Now I call this in a bash script

`python pythonscript.py >> temp.txt`

If I `kill` the process no data is logged.

Comment: I wonder that it works that way -- but the easiest thing to come up with would be turning your function into a separate shell script to be called instead. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: It would be extremely difficult to do this. Looking for a simpler solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you mention it is not a shell function, but a python function in a python script: That explains some, and here comes your answer:

[printing - How to flush output of Python print? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

You need to put that inside your python function's loop: `sys.stdout.flush()` -- and of course you need to `import sys` before (or `from sys import ...` if you only need a part of it).